# How to remove dynamically added row using j Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding rows to my table by cloning it. When the user clicks on the `Delete Row` button a checkbox should appear at the starting of every row which when selected remove that particular row.

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id01" name="row">
      <td>


        <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="GDS">Guides</option>
          <option value="LOF">Latest Offers</option>
          <option value="TEM">Templates</option>
          <option value="VID">Videos</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}" />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}" />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}" />

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button4" value="Delete Row" class="delButtons" name="Button4" type="button" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
$("#dataTable").on('click', '.delButtons', function () {
var $tr = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
$tr.remove();
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: They need to click Delete button again to delete the selected rows?

Comment: Try : $('#dataTable tr:last').remove()

Comment: *a checkbox should appear at the start of every row* - there's no code for this - is this your requirement? Are you asking us **to write the code for you**?  Where's your attempt to add this checkbox?

Comment: SInce i am a beginner in jQuery so i want to know if using jQuery i can add  checkbox dynamically when 'Delete Row' button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code to add checkbox on click of delete button and remove row on click of newly added checkbox

```js
$(function(){
   $('.delButtons').on('click', function(){
       $('#dataTable thead tr').each(function(){
          if($(this).find('.removeBtnHeader').length==0) {
            $(this).find('td:first').before('<td class="removeBtnHeader"></td>');
          }
       });
       $('#dataTable tbody tr').each(function(){
          if($(this).find('.removeBtn').length==0) {
            $(this).find('td:first').before('<td><input type="checkbox" class="removeBtn"></td>');
          }
       });
   });
   
   $(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function(){
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id01" name="row">
      <td>


        <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()" >
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="GDS">Guides</option>
          <option value="LOF">Latest Offers</option>
          <option value="TEM">Templates</option>
          <option value="VID">Videos</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="id02" name="row">
      <td>


        <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()" >
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="GDS">Guides</option>
          <option value="LOF">Latest Offers</option>
          <option value="TEM">Templates</option>
          <option value="VID">Videos</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
        <div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button4" value="Delete Row" class="delButtons" name="Button4" type="button" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the code doesn't seem to be working as only one checkbox is appearing at the top of the table and not adjacent to each row.

Comment: try updated answer and let me know if that works for you or not

Comment: Yes it worked.Thanks for that. The only problem i am getting is the checkboxes are coming at the top of each row and not adjacent to it. Do i need to do any changes in my html for that?

Comment: If you're writing a UI the way this currently works, please don't.   Tick boxes should be tickable *and untickable* - this should be a button, not a tickbox.

Comment: @Saurav, freedomn-m is correct, you should have button instead of checkboxes or you can add checkboxes while adding new row and first select the checkboxes of rows which are to be deleted and then click on delete button at the bottom.